# Detect Trident 6+ for performance reasons

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

What is the best way to detect Trident 6.0+ with JavaScript? I know browser detection is bad, but I'm building a web app which needs to run on Trident 6.0+ for performance reasons. You can't use [Modernizr](http://www.modernizr.com/) to detect performance in layout engines.

I'm not worried about the *reliability* of the detection, because if users are savvy enough to get around JavaScript detection then I'm sure they'll understand if the web app doesn't work correctly. ;)

What I have tried so far:

```
var ua = navigator.userAgent;
isTri6 = ua.match(/Trident\/6/i);
isTri7 = ua.match(/Trident\/7/i);
if( !isTri6 | !isTri7 ) { console.warn("Not running on Trident 6+"); }
```

This doesn't throw any errors, but it does warn the console for Chrome, Firefox, and IE10 & IE11. (It shouldn't warn IE10+) If you have a way to do it without the use of the user agent (such as conditional comments) please tell me. I have also tried using conditional comments but that ends with the same result.

Any input would be much appreciated!

Comment: What kind of performance is too slow on the older versions? The best way to detect implementations that are too slow would be to run some sort of performance test when the code loads and see whether it's underperforming. This would catch any browser that's slow and also allow for polyfill implementations that might perform better on older browsers.

Comment: @DaveMethvin Not that type of performance. I'm talking about text-rendering on Windows 8 (IE10 & IE11) as well as specific Javascript performances. I'm building an experimental web application using things that are native to Windows 8 OS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you probably want to throw the warning when the agent is not Trident 6 and not Trident 7:

```
if( !isTri6 && !isTri7 ) { ... }
```

The old condition was triggering if the agent was not Trident 6 **or** not Trident 7, which was always true.

Secondly, Chrome and Firefox will throw the warning, as neither one uses the Trident layout engine at all! You may want to revise your conditions accordingly.